# How can I solve phpmyadmin table error?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I found table error phpmyadmin.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the "lv_sessions browse table" page and click the repair button as indicated in the image below:
[image]

Alternatively, you could open the SQL command window and execute:

```
REPAIR TABLE `lv_sessions`
```

Answer (score 0):

I looks like your table is crashed. 
Try to execute this query:

```
REPAIR TABLE `lv_sessions`
```